# Set firebase functions config with secret environment variable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

What is the recommended way to set an environment variable for a firebase function that originates from the google kms?

In my cloudbuild.yaml I have following step:

```
  # Set env
  - name: 'gcr.io/$_PROJECT_ID/firebase'    
    args: ['functions:config:set', 'env.environment=$_ENV', 'env.build=$BUILD_ID','api_key=$API_KEY', '--project', '$_PROJECT_ID']
    dir: 'functions'    
    secretEnv: ['API_KEY','FIREBASE_TOKEN']
```

For the custom google cloud builder I followed the instructions from 
Follow instructions from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/

The cloudbuild.yaml is either being invalidated or the substitution does not work.

**Edit:**

Error message

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid build: key in the template "API_KEY" is not a valid built-in substitution
```

If I retrieve the firebase environment through `firebase functions:config:get` I see `$API_KEY` or `$$API_KEY` or `API_KEY` depending on the substitution strategy chosen. 
If I add the unencrypted API_KEY to the environment variables in the Google Cloud Build Trigger, the substitution works as expected.

Comment: Looking at the step everything seems fine according to the [documentation samples](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#build_steps)


The only thing I notice is that you have a typo in the first string on the “args” list. You are missing a single quote: 


functions:config:set' should be ‘functions:config:set'.


If that is not the source of your issue, it would be good to have more information about the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I edited the initial question. The substitution does not happen and I end up having the string `API_KEY` as my environment variable. 
Not sure if using a secretEnv as part of the args is the recommended way

Answer (score 0):

I have been following the github instructions link as you did:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/

It worked fine for me. Just to confirm that you did not miss any step, did you repeat the same steps needed to create the firebase-token and applied them to the API_KEY?

```
#### create a key for the api token
gcloud kms keys create api-token --location global --keyring cloudbuilder --purpose encryption

#### create the encrypted token
echo -n $API_TOKEN | gcloud kms encrypt \
  --plaintext-file=- \
  --ciphertext-file=- \
  --location=global \
  --keyring=cloudbuilder \
  --key=api-token | base64
```

Also I had to add another secret to the cloudbuild.yaml:

```
Secrets:
- kmsKeyName: 'projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/global/keyRings/cloudbuilder/cryptoKeys/firebase-token'
  secretEnv:
    FIREBASE_TOKEN: '<YOUR_ENCRYPTED_TOKEN>'

- kmsKeyName: 'projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/global/keyRings/cloudbuilder/cryptoKeys/api-token'
  secretEnv:
    API_TOKEN: '<YOUR_ENCRYPTED_TOKEN>'
```

Hope that helps!